# Test visualforce form submission

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test

I'm trying to write an apex test for submitting a Visualforce apex:form.  The page is very basic:

```
<apex:page controller="MyController">
  <apex:form>
    <apex:inputField value="{!settings.val1__c}"/>
    <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The controller is also basic:

```
public with sharing class MyController {
  public MySettings__c settings {get; set;}

  public MyController() {
    settings = MySettings__c.getOrgDefaults();
    if (settings == null || settings.id == null) {
      upsert new MySettings__c(SetupOwnerId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId());
      settings = MySettings__c.getOrgDefaults();
  }

  public PageReference save() {
    update settings;
    return null;
  }
}
```

In the test class, I have gotten only this far:

```
PageReference page = new PageReference('/apex/MyPage');
Test.setCurrentPage(page);
```

And now I am at a loss as to how to fill in values for my VF page so that I can try saving it and make sure that the value was saved.  Any idea how I can fill in VF form values from an apex test?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Visualforce components just access the controller's properties and methods, so in your test class you call those directly.

Example:

```
// Arrange the components
MySettings__c originalValue = MySettings__c.getOrgDefaults();
PageReference pageRef = Page.YourPageNameHere;
Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);      
MyController controller = new MyController();

// Act
controller.settings.val1__c = 'New value';
controller.save();
MySettings__c updatedValue = [SOQL to retrieve new object];

// Assert
System.assertEquals(updatedValue, originalValue, 'Error message');
```

See the [developer docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_error_handling.htm) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to create an instance of your controller, set the field, then check it was set correctly. Something like this:

```
String testVal = 'TESTVAL';
MyController() c = new MyController();
c.settings.val1__c = testVal;
c.save();
System.assertEquals(testVal, MySettings__c.getOrgDefaults().val1__c, 
    'Saved setting is not correct!');
```